# Family members visitors visas applications

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I suffer from a debilitating illness; an "end of life" kidney disease, and I'm incapable of travelling to visit my close family in Algeria. I used to visit my parents once a year but now that I'm on a daily peritoneal dialysis, I cannot afford to do that anymore and my fluids are not even available in Algeria. I can't work at the moment and I wanted to invite my close family members to come and visit me as soon as possible. I really don't know what to do... I thought about shipping my fluids to Algeria but it ended up being very pricey and risky. My only hope is family visitors visas ...

Comment: My sincere sympathies to you. I wish you the best. That said, what is your question? Your situation is not different from many people. You will not get any preferential treatment. Your family still have to qualify for a visitors visa.

Comment: My question is: Is it possible to write a personal statement joined by my medical certificates to support their application and speed up the process?

Comment: @Hanna Naidja Your medical certificates would help support the purpose of the visit, but wouldn’t in themselves speed up the process, or resolve any visa eligibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

The [TLScontact center Algiers Added Value Service](https://uk.tlscontact.com/dz/alg/page.php?pid=added_value_services), fee-based, may expedite the process. If your family members are applying in a category such as the Standard Visitor visa, they might receive a decision in as few as 5 working days. The Priority Visa Service (settlement) usually returns a decision within 30 days.

> **Priority Visa Service (non settlement)**
>
> **How long does a Priority Visa application take?**
>   UKVI aims to make a decision on your Priority Visa application, and contact you to let you know that your passport is ready to be collected within 5 working days from when you submit your biometric information.
>
> **Priority Visa Service (settlement)**
>   You can pay for a Priority Visa service which puts your family migration / settlement application at the front of the queue at every stage of the decision-making process. The cost of this service is in addition to your visa application fee and is non-refundable if the visa application is refused, or in exceptional cases, takes longer to process. Using the Priority Visa service does not imply or guarantee that your application will be successful. All visa applicants must meet the requirements of the UK.

In all cases, note that there are exclusions (those who may not use priority) and exceptions (applications pulled from the queue, for any number of reasons), and the turnaround time is not guaranteed.

Comment: I would not pay extra to speed up the process when you know the applicants have low probability of being granted the visa. You only lose the ridiculous expediting fee